# How to write HTML entities using Rails Nokogiri gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri, html-entities

I was using Nokogiri gem to write some xml data.
I need a tag like this:-

```
<CURRENCYNAME>₹</CURRENCYNAME>
```

The problem is that Nokogiri writes symbol code (₹) instead of ₹. Below is a snippet from my code:-

```
  data = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
          xml.CURRENCYNAME "₹"
         end
  response.headers["file_name"] = "Master.xml"
  send_data data.to_xml, filename: "Master.xml", type: "application/xml"
```

Result that I get in my Master.xml file:-

```
<CURRENCYNAME>&#x20B9;</CURRENCYNAME>
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? Aren't they rendered with the same result?

Comment: No in the file, &#x20B9; is written instead of ₹, and I need the xml to transfer data to some other software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use encoding as argument for `to_xml` method:

```
irb(main):013:0> Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new { |xml|xml.CURRENCYNAME "₹" }.to_xml(encoding: 'UTF-8')

=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<CURRENCYNAME>₹</CURRENCYNAME>\n"
```